# Dovecot configuration with multi-account offlineimap syncing

Tags: email, imap

I use `offlineimap` to synchronize several IMAP accounts into the following directory structure where each `AccntN` is a synchronized remote IMAP account in Maildir format.

```
$HOME/Mails/Accnt1
$HOME/Mails/Accnt2
$HOME/Mails/Accnt3
etc...
```

My goal is to have Dovecot serve each account separately so that I can access them using Thunderbird. I'm having a difficult time figuring this out. So far it seems that I need to use virtual users, but it's unclear to me how to map the virtual user to the paths above.

A minimal Dovecot configuration for this would be great (note auth can be as simple as possible -- this is a single user / localhost-only setup).